# How to display Mother and Father of a person separately from same table in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Person table
[image: Person table]

PersonParent table(relation)
[image: PersonParent table(relation)]

How to display all the records of person table, with their parents, whether or not having parents?

Output
[image: Output]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the output view would look like?

Comment: just do a self left join. https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-self-join/#:~:text=The%20self%2Djoin%20is%20a,rows%20within%20the%20same%20table.

Comment: Output should be name of Mother and Father for every person, If there are not mother or father, they should be null.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

that would be :
here is how to join to get the parents information alongside with person info , however this way , the person row will repeat for each parent :

```
select p.*, concat_ws(',',parent.firstname , parent_lastname) as ParentName
from persons p
cross join (select * 
left join PersonParent pp
   on p.personId = pp.personId
left join persons parent
   on pp.parentId = parent.personid
```

if you want to show only one row per person, you can use query below, I used gender column to distinguish between mother and father:

```
select * from persons p
left join lateral(
    select max(concat_ws(',', parents.firstname, parents.lastname)) filter (where parents.gender = 'm') as fatherrname
         , max(concat_ws(',', parents.firstname, parents.lastname)) filter (where parents.gender = 'f') as mothername
    from personparents pp 
    join persons parents on pp.parentid = parents.id
    where pp.personid = p.id 
    group by pp.personid
) pp on true
```

Comment: 'max' is wrong, it always receives only on pair of parent.

Comment: how to write it without max

Comment: @DahamWijekoon why you say max is wrong? , prepare a fiddle and show me what you mean ( www.dbfiddle.uk)